# Why Kivy App.root instance does not recognize root member method after built by Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am making a small Kivy app, it basically works fine in development environment.
However, it crashed when I launch the built exe file.

build command used:
`pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

Basically, the method *store_section()* is defined in RootWidget and should be called from *on_start()* method of App instance. And eveything just works well by invoking directly to main.py (*python main.py*).
Even Pyinstaller built successfully, I got the following error message when launching the corresponding exe file. The error said:
"**AttributeError: 'Widget' object has no attribute 'store_sections'**".

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\hoang\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-06-03_46.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI93602\kivy\__init__.pyc"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "D:\ielts\dist\main.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 26.20.100.7927'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 26.20.100.7927'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 152, in <module>
     IeltsApp().run()
   File "kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
   File "kivy\app.py", line 944, in _run_prepare
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "main.py", line 148, in on_start
     self.root.store_sections()
 AttributeError: 'Widget' object has no attribute 'store_sections'
[2264] Failed to execute script main
```

Below is main.py and kv file.

main.py

```
class Section(GridLayout):
    sectionNumber = NumericProperty(None)
    questions = ListProperty([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    sections = []
    
    # Other methods and properties are removed for short

    def store_sections(self):
        self.sections.append(self.sectionOne)
        self.sections.append(self.sectionTwo)
        self.sections.append(self.sectionThree)
        self.sections.append(self.sectionFour)


class IeltsApp(App):

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.store_sections()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    IeltsApp().run()
```

ielts.kv file

```
RootWidget:
    sectionOne: sectionOne
    sectionTwo: sectionTwo
    sectionThree: sectionThree
    sectionFour: sectionFour

    GridLayout:
        size_hint: (1, .95)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': (root.height - self.height)/root.height}
        cols: 2
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                rows: 2
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                Section:
                    id: sectionOne
                    sectionNumber: 1
                    questions: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                Section:
                    id: sectionTwo
                    sectionNumber: 2
                    questions: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                rows: 2
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                Section:
                    id: sectionThree
                    sectionNumber: 3
                    questions: [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
                Section:
                    id: sectionFour
                    sectionNumber: 4
                    questions: [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
```

Could someone please help me tackle this error?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Clearly `self.root` isn't what you expect, so what is it and where did it come from? Understanding this will probably help lead to understanding the problem.

Comment: Kv code is stored in a file named ielts.kv, so kivy framework automatically loads kv structure from there after initiating IeltsApp().run(), thus self.root is the instance of RootWidget. Sorry for not clarifying clearly in my question..

Comment: That's what it's supposed to be, not what (according to the error) it is. You should look into that. For instance, what happens if you comment out `self.root.store_sections()`, do you see the widget you expect?

Comment: I’ll try rebuilding after commenting out that line and update you then

Comment: You're right, @inclement. After commenting out ```self.root.store_sections()```, the app just display a black window and ```self.root``` is actually ```kivy.uix.widget.Widget```, that explains why it does not have attribute ```store_sections```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `kv` file will be automatically included in the `.exe`. Try running:

```
pyinstaller --add-data 'ielts.kv';'.' --onefile main.py
```

Comment: Hi @John, build failed after applying the flags as your suggestion, ```WARNING: stderr: Unable to find "D:\ielts\'ielts.kv'" when adding binary and data files.```

Comment: It works fine after removing the quotation marks. final successful command is `pyinstaller --add-data ielts.kv;. --onefile main.py` Thanks @John